# XCODE 4.3.1 and libcrypto.a and libsqlcipher.a, building debug and release

Tags: xcode, sqlite, encryption

Have added the Xcode Projects for openssl.xcodeproj and sqlcipher.xcodeproj in a current project and if I build for RELEASE, everything is ok.  If I build for DEBUG, the linked does not seem to be able to resolve / find the libsqlcipher.a file.  I have taken the two project out of the main project and built by hand in RELEASE / DEBUG and generated the lib files, but if I set the main project to DEBUG, it still will not resolve even though the lib files are added to the link list.

Why would the linker have problems resolving the entry points when the main project is set to DEBUG?

Comment: Well, finally got it be making sure that target and architectures are correct (armv6 armv7).  And valid architectures are correct.  And proper base SDK.  Will answer my own question when I can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to fool with the two projets to make sure that armv6 AND armv7 were present along with valid architectures and the correct base sdk.